# Flex: HDividedBox not detecting double click event

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe

This is how I defined HDividedBox:

```
<mx:HDividedBox id="hdivider" height="100%" width="100%" horizontalGap="15" doubleClickEnabled="true" doubleClick="resize(event)">
```

and the resize method is

```
private function resize(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 trace("comes here");
}
```

But doubleclick event never reaches the resize(). What is wrong with my code?

Comment: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=183377

Comment: @ethrbunny there is another doubleclick event on my application.

Comment: Are the two fighting over who gets the event?